# How to gzip a file on google cloud platform from one bucket to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to **gzip** a file on Google Cloud Platform.

I am unable to do it. I am trying since many days. I studied many answers but none of them asked this straight.

So if i have file gs://source/data.csv **6gb**

I want output on new bucket gs://target/data.csv.gz **1.5gb**

cp -z or -Z options are not changing file size . Do we have one liner command to do same.

Command tried are :-

```
user@cloudshell:~ (userx)$ gsutil cp -z text/csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/usuals_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv.gz
Copying gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
- [1 files][ 31.7 MiB/ 31.7 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/31.7 MiB.
user@cloudshell:~ (userx)$ gsutil cp -z text/gzip gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv.gz                                                                                                                              
Copying gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
- [1 files][ 31.7 MiB/ 31.7 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/31.7 MiB.
user@cloudshell:~ (userx)$ gsutil cp -z text/plain gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P1.csv.gz                                                                                                                            
Copying gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
- [1 files][ 31.7 MiB/ 31.7 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/31.7 MiB.
user@cloudshell:~ (userx)$ gsutil cp -z gzip gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P1.csv.gz                                                                                                                                  
Copying gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
- [1 files][ 31.7 MiB/ 31.7 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/31.7 MiB.
user@cloudshell:~ (userx)$ gsutil cp -z application/gzip gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P1.csv.gz                                                                                                                                  
Copying gs://databucket/xyzppp/test_folder/XXXX_1_0_20200412084238_P.csv [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
- [1 files][ 31.7 MiB/ 31.7 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/31.7 MiB.
```

**Below is the example** , I am trying to gzip small file first before I do it on 18 gb file. We can notice file size remain same after -z option. where as if i copy same file on linux and run `"gzip filename"`, its size becomes 6mb.

[image: an example for doing same with 37 mb file]

Comment: What is the command? What is the result?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have updated the commands tried. I am expecting result to be a gz format and with lesser size. (Like we do on unix "gzip file"). I have to send file to client in gzip format.

Comment: You are copying "bucket" to "bucket". You need to download the objects first to enable compression. Bucket to bucket is an object copy operation performed by Google Cloud Storage and not an "upload" operation performed by `gsutil`. The upload operation supports compression.

Comment: But would not that be slow as I ll have to download file and then gzip it. is not there any one liner command to do it on GCP. (or any faster approach)

Comment: If you want to compress files already in Google Cloud Storage, you will need to download them somewhere (your desktop, a VM in the cloud) and then compress them. Google Cloud Storage does not offer processing features such as compressing already existing items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John commented and as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

> Because the -z/-Z options compress data prior to upload

You cannot use the -Z flag to compress files already uploaded.

If you want to compress files already uploaded to Google Cloud Storage you can use the [Dataflow templates for Bulk Compress](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities).

This can be done using a single command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
    --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Bulk_Compress_GCS_Files \
    --parameters \
inputFilePattern=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/uncompressed/*.txt,\
outputDirectory=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/compressed,\
outputFailureFile=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/failed/failure.csv,\
compression=COMPRESSION
```

Or you can perform this compression on the Console by following the documention linked above.